# Concat Arrays in React/JavaScript via prevState

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

This is my actually code:

```
class Notifications extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      newNotifications: null, //this always must be a null in constructor.
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.props.isNewNotification !== prevProps.isNewNotification) {
      this.setState({
        newNotifications: prevProps.newNotifications,
      });
    }
  }
...
```

My prevProps.newNotifications is an array, for example:

```
[{"date_time":"Wednesday, 19:42","amount_money":"2,10 USD","sender_name":"John Polaszek"}]
```

I would like to merge array my `prevProps.newNotifications` in `prevState.newNotifications` when `prevState.newNotifications` isn't a null. In `render()` i have this method:

```
{newNotifications ? (
          <div className="no-test">
                {newNotifications.map((newNotification, id) => (
                    <Fragment>
                          <span>
                            {newNotification.sender_name}
                          </span>
                          <span className="notification_amount">
                            {newNotification.amount_money}
                          </span>
                        </span>
                        <br />
                        <span>
                          {newNotification.date_time}
                        </span>
                    </Fragment>
                ))}
          </div>
        )...
```

How can I do this? I hope my question is understandable.

Comment: Is the `newNotification` being added not passed in as part of the props ?

Answer (score 0):

In your `componentDidUpdate` method, you have the right idea, you just need to either set, or [Array.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), depending on the condition.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (this.props.isNewNotification !== prevProps.isNewNotification) {
    let newNotifications;

    if (prevState.newNotifications !== null) {
      newNotifications = prevState.newNotifications.concat(prevProps.newNotifications);
    } else {
      // otherwise, set newNotifications to your other condition
    }

    this.setState({ newNotifications }); // computed property since the var is the same as the state name
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't think this would cut it. You will have duplicates at some point as you seem to be concating `prevState.newNotifications` twice for each update

Comment: @Sushanth-- unfortunately we don't know enough context to help more, the main thing is that OP can use `Array.concat` to merge. Other options (lodash is a good one) will be better for deep-no-dupe merging

Comment: Also `prevState. newNotifications` will always be a stale copy.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can keep it as an empty array instead of null. You can just use the spread operator.

```
class Notifications extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      newNotifications: [], // maintain it as an array instead.
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.props.isNewNotification !== prevProps.isNewNotification) {
      const newNotifications = [...prevState.newNotifications, ...prevProps.newNotifications];
      this.setState({
        newNotifications,
      });
    }
  }
```

This does not remove duplicates, you can try to use underscore or lodash or write a function yourself to remove them.

```
union(prevProps.newNotifications, prevState.newNotifications);
```

union or uniq or uniqBy can do the job for you.

[http://underscorejs.org](http://underscorejs.org/#union)

[http://lodash.com/docs](http://lodash.com/docs#union)

2. And in the render function, you can change your ternary operator to check for length, if length is 0 (as in the initialisation), the else part will be executed.

```
{newNotifications.length ? (
          <div className="no-test">
                {newNotifications.map((newNotification, id) => (
                    <Fragment>
                          <span>
                            {newNotification.sender_name}
                          </span>
                          <span className="notification_amount">
                            {newNotification.amount_money}
                          </span>
                        </span>
                        <br />
                        <span>
                          {newNotification.date_time}
                        </span>
                    </Fragment>
                ))}
          </div>
        )...
```

Comment: Also `prevState. newNotifications` will always be a stale copy

Comment: Yup, I don't know what he is trying to achieve. I believe he wants to consolidate all notifications to show notification history in some kind of popup may be? If he provides more context, we can try to solve it better.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to add this as a comment, but it's too long.

If I'm understanding your question correctly, the others have answered your question, however, you shouldn't be doing what you're asking to do.

I can tell you're aiming to be declarative and handle things through props, but there's remnants of imperative thinking that are complicating things.  From what I can tell, when the parent component has new notifications it will pass both the `newNotifications` and `isNewNotification`.  Then it would flip `isNewNotification` back to `false`.  Whenever you have a sequence to things, you're thinking imperatively, not declaratively.  Reaching for lifecycle methods is also an indication that you're thinking imperatively (though this is sometimes necessary).

You're essentially trying to replicate a function call with props.  I think you'd actually be better off exposing an `addNotifications` method, getting a `ref` to the component and calling the method, rather than this declarative-looking-but-really-imperative api.

But really, we don't want to expose an imperative api for components to communicate.  If the parent is responsible for adding the new notifications, it's probably in a better position to maintain the notifications list.  I'm guessing these notifications are coming from an api or a websocket.  When they are received, this is the place to concat the new notifications and store that back in the parent's state.  The child then can become just a stateless component.

```
class NotificationParent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      notifications: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    api.on("notifications", newNotifications => {
       this.setState(({ notifications } => {
         if (!notifications) {
           return {
             notifications: newNotifications
           };
         } else {
           return {
             notifications: notifications.concat(newNotifications)
           };
         }
       });
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Notifications notifications={this.state.notifications}/>
    );
  }
}

function Notification({ notifications }) {
  return (
    newNotifications ? (
       <div className="no-test">
         {newNotifications.map((newNotification, id) => (
           <Fragment>
             <span>
               {newNotification.sender_name}
             </span>
             <span className="notification_amount">
               {newNotification.amount_money}
             </span>
             <br />
             <span>
               {newNotification.date_time}
             </span>
           </Fragment>
         ))}
      </div>
    ) : (
      /* ... */
    )
  )
}
```